# Adding app insights logging inside AD B2C Display Controls (emailVerificationControl)

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

We implemented a custom email verification workflow through send grid and it works great.  We want to add app insights logging to know how many are putting their email but not verifying it. Calling AppInsights-EmailVerificationSent Technical Profile in the display control below is giving me a "Unable to validate the information provided." error.  How can I call this technical profile to log the action in app insights?  Thanks very much!

```
<TechnicalProfile Id="AppInsights-Common">
          <DisplayName>Application Insights</DisplayName>
          <Protocol Name="Proprietary" Handler="Web.TPEngine.Providers.Insights.AzureApplicationInsightsProvider, Web.TPEngine, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
          <Metadata>
            <Item Key="InstrumentationKey">xxxxx</Item>
            <Item Key="DeveloperMode">true</Item>
            <Item Key="DisableTelemetry ">false</Item>
          </Metadata>
          <InputClaims>
            <!-- Properties of an event are added through the syntax {property:NAME}, where NAME is property being added to the event. DefaultValue can be either a static value or a value that's resolved by one of the supported DefaultClaimResolvers. -->
            <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="EventTimestamp" PartnerClaimType="{property:EventTimestamp}" DefaultValue="{Context:DateTimeInUtc}" />
            <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="PolicyId" PartnerClaimType="{property:Policy}" DefaultValue="{Policy:PolicyId}" />
            <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="CorrelationId" PartnerClaimType="{property:CorrelationId}" DefaultValue="{Context:CorrelationId}" />
            <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="Culture" PartnerClaimType="{property:Culture}" DefaultValue="{Culture:RFC5646}" />
          </InputClaims>
        </TechnicalProfile>
        <TechnicalProfile Id="AppInsights-EmailVerificationSent">
          <InputClaims>
            <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="EventType" PartnerClaimType="eventName" DefaultValue="EmailVerificationSent" />
            <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" PartnerClaimType="{property:UserId}" DefaultValue="NoValue" />
          </InputClaims>
          <IncludeTechnicalProfile ReferenceId="AppInsights-Common" />
        </TechnicalProfile>


<DisplayControls>
      <DisplayControl Id="emailVerificationControl" UserInterfaceControlType="VerificationControl">
        <DisplayClaims>
        <DisplayClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" Required="true" />
        <DisplayClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="verificationCode" ControlClaimType="VerificationCode" Required="true" />
        </DisplayClaims>
        <OutputClaims>
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" />
        </OutputClaims>
        <Actions>
          <Action Id="SendCode">
            <ValidationClaimsExchange>              
              <ValidationClaimsExchangeTechnicalProfile TechnicalProfileReferenceId="GenerateOtp" />              
              <ValidationClaimsExchangeTechnicalProfile TechnicalProfileReferenceId="SendOtp" />
              **<ValidationClaimsExchangeTechnicalProfile TechnicalProfileReferenceId="AppInsights-EmailVerificationSent" />**
            </ValidationClaimsExchange>                       
          </Action>
          <Action Id="VerifyCode">
            <ValidationClaimsExchange>
            <ValidationClaimsExchangeTechnicalProfile TechnicalProfileReferenceId="VerifyOtp" />
            **<ValidationClaimsExchangeTechnicalProfile TechnicalProfileReferenceId="AppInsights-EmailVerified" />**
            </ValidationClaimsExchange>
          </Action>
        </Actions>
      </DisplayControl>
    </DisplayControls>
```

Answer (score 0):

Having had this exact problem recently the only way I found was to set up an API endpoint that would write custom events to App Insights, then use a REST technical profile to call that API from the `DisplayControl`.